# Restricting 3 figures after the decimal places is not working when copy paste value into the input field

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I was successful in restricting the 3 figures after the decimal places however the fix is not working when i copy paste some random decimal figures into the text field.

```js
$('.min-val').on('keyup', function(e) {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''));
  if ($(this).val().indexOf(".") > -1 && ($(this).val().split('.')[1].length > 3)) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, $(this).val().length - 1));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="min val" class="min-val" />
```

How can i restrict the decimal figures to 3 even when i copy paste the data?

Comment: It's because you're only using the `keyup` event. Try `on('input paste', function(e) {...`

Comment: @Roy thanks for the answer. I tried with the on('input paste', function(e) {... but it not helping..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with regex itself. I am not good at it though.
So below work around works.
You can determine the number of characters to trim and use that number
`var charsToTrim = $(this).val().split('.')[1].length - 3;`

```js
$('.min-val').on('keyup', function(e) {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''));
  if ($(this).val().indexOf(".") > -1 && ($(this).val().split('.')[1].length > 3)) {
    var charsToTrim = $(this).val().split('.')[1].length - 3;
    $(this).val($(this).val().substring(0, $(this).val().length - charsToTrim));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="min val" class="min-val" />
```